# What does mytheme mean?

Tags: folkloristics, terminology

What is the meaning of the term mytheme?

When did the term first come into use, and what are some examples of mythemes?

Comment: Hi, Baldr, welcome to Mythology and Folklore. Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mytheme), and if so, what still confuses you?

Comment: @HDE226868 possibly they're looking for an explanation in layman's language.  *(I'm thinking of my first brush with Time Complexity as a non-mathematician.)*  The wiki is clear, but assumes general grounding in linguistics.

Answer (score 5):

[Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mytheme) provides us with the following definition:

> *In structuralist anthropology and literary criticism*:
>
> each of a set of fundamental generic units of narrative structure (typically involving a relationship between a character, an event, and a theme) from which myths are thought to be constructed.

It is, in effect, a common ground between different mythological stories.

Vampires and Selkies for example might be based on a mytheme of shapeshifting.

Hades and Nirvana may have the mytheme of the afterlife.

I hope this answers your question.